# Derivation of the QFT Propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, dirac-delta-distributions, greens-functions, propagator

I don't understand how we get from the RHS to the last line.

\begin{eqnarray}
\left[ \hat{H}_x - i \frac{\partial}{\partial t_x} \right] G^+(x,t_x,y,t_y)  &=& -i \delta (t_x - t_y) \sum_n{\phi_n(x) \phi_n^* (y) e^{-i E_n (t_x - t_y)}}\\ &=& - i \delta(t_x - t_y) \delta(x - y)
\end{eqnarray}

I understand that
$\sum_n \phi_n(x) \phi_n^*(y) = \delta(x-y)$
But I can't figure out where the.
$\sum_n e^{iE_n(t_x-t_y)}$ goes to.

Comment: Hint: $\delta(t)f(t)=\delta(t)f(0)$.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is:
$$ \sum_0^{N-1} e^{-iEn(t_x-t_y)} = N\delta(t_x-t_y) $$

Comment: Erm I don't understand, how did you get that relation? Also if you have an $N$, wouldn't the answer be $-iN \delta(t_x-t_y) \delta(x-y)$ ?